# How can I convert a 30FPS video to 50FPS video without affecting the length of the video?

Tags: framerate, frame-interpolation

How can I interplote a 30FPS video to a 50 FPS video without affecting the length of the video?

I have used the VSDC video editor to do so. I have set the reframing mode to optical flow.
However, I found that it just inserted a previous frame between the adjacent frames.

I have tried the mkvtoolnix, unfortunately, it just shortened the video duration.

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1):

[Several commercial solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_rate#Instruments) seem only to support full integers as multipliers for frame rate conversion. Assuming VSDC works a similar way, thus you might try to go via the LCM of 30 and 50 frames per second and first do a upconversion to 150 frames/sec and afterwards reduce it to 50 frames/sec.
Sadly [the official docs](https://www.videosoftdev.com/how-to-achieve-perfect-slow-motion-effect-with-reframing) do not say anything about that.